Cannot import LoginKit from @snapchat/snap-kit-react-native
React-Native (Expo) App. Followed documentation and cannot import LoginKit.
When imported, LoginKit returns as null, e.g.:
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "../contexts/AuthContext";
import { LoginKit } from "@snapchat/snap-kit-react-native";

export default function EditProfilePicture() {
  const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);
  console.log(LoginKit); // prints as null
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => LoginKit.login()}> 
        <Text>LOGIN</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

Of course, when button is pressed:
// Cannot read property 'login' of null

I have followed instructions on documentation located here: https://docs.snap.com/snap-kit/login-kit/Tutorials/react-native
I have attempted to reinstall package
Nothing is working.

Use the default import instead of named.
import LoginKit from '@snapchat/snap-kit-react-native';

See API reference for details.

Still did not work.
